# StatusBar SimpleText property not found VB 6

Tags: vb6

I want to change some logic in a `VB6` project, when I run the project I get

```
Method or data member not found
```

on this line:

```
Me.StatusBar1.SimpleText = "test"
```

I've searched a lot but couldn't find my case.
I think I have some missing libraries in my project.
Any information about how to get rid of this error would be very useful.

Comment: I think the issue is the referenced library that you are using.  There are two libraries that contains the StatusBar control:  
  
Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0  
Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0  
  
I'm not sure which library has the StatusBar with SimpleText property. But you can just simply test each one.  
  
For further info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231207(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much, it was what I looked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the referenced library that you are using.

**There are two libraries that contains the StatusBar control**:

- Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0
- Microsoft Windows Common    Controls 6.0

I'm not sure which library has the StatusBar with SimpleText property. But you can just simply test each one.

For further info: [Upgrading Applications that Use the Windows Common Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231207(v=vs.60).aspx)

---

*[This answer based on a comment left on the question]*